# Setting a pointer to null segfault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a struct called node as follows:

```
struct node {
    int data;
}
```

stored in some structure:

```
struct structure {
  struct node *pointer;
}
```

I'm trying to set pointer to NULL as follows:

```
struct structure *elements;
elements->pointer = NULL;
```

Why does this segfault? Does it actually attempt to dereference the pointer before setting it to null?

When I switch `elements` from a pointer to the actual struct and do the following:

```
struct structure elements;
elements.pointer = NULL;
```

It stops segfaulting and works. Why doesn't setting a pointer to null work?

Comment: wow, this question was resolved quickly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct structure *elements;
elements->pointer = NULL;
```

`elements` pointer points to nowhere. Dereferencing an invalid pointer (`elements` pointer) is undefined behavior.

You need to initialize `elements` pointer to a valid object, like:

```
struct structure my_struct;
struct structure *elements = &my_struct;
elements->pointer = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the pointer

```
struct structure *elements = malloc(sizeof(struct structure));
```

If you don't do this it will point to a arbitrary memory location.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid pointer you're derefrencing, thus the segfault, is not `elements->pointer`, but `elements` itself. Since it has not been set (e.g.: by a `malloc`), it could point to any location in memory.

Comment: He's dereferencing an **uninitialized** pointer. It may or may not be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't initialize `*elements`.

`*elements` right now points to nothing, so `elements->pointer` is dereferencing nothing, which gives you your segfault.

Comment: He's dereferencing an **uninitialized** pointer. It may or may not be `null`.

Comment: Stop downvoting everyone on a technicality, @Graham, and I've editted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`elements` hasn't been initialized to point to anything yet.